# finally block execute before the break,continue,return statement of try clause in python

Tags: python, try-catch, break, finally

finally block execute before the break or continue or return statement of try clause in python then why the output of this code is different

```py
def bool_return():
    try:
        return print("foo")
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        return "ola"

print(bool_return())
```

output is:

```
foo ola
```

why ?

Comment: The code does exactly what the documentation  says. The `finally` block executes before `return`. So it prints 98 than the finally block which prints 99 and then returns `ok`.

Comment: for more information go through python doc

Comment: Specifically, [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) in the python docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning something is the last thing a function can do. After returning something, Python will continue doing what it did before or end the script.

If Python would return immediately, this would be the end of the function. The finally-block is thought to be ran no matter what happens, therefore it has to run first, even if the original return gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

the finally block is some thing where we write the code for closing the connections to other servers . If in case we returned from the statement we will have the connections opened so it will be executed before moving out of function. 
We can check if we write a return in final block and try block which one is executing

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```py
def bool_return():
    try:
        return print("foo")
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        return print("ola")

print(bool_return())
```

is using a `finally` clause. The finally clause is executed before the exiting from the owning `try`/`except` block. This means that your could is turned in to the following (pseudocode!):

```
function bool_return():
    do in case of errors goto Errors:
        var r = print("foo") < this is the statement in the try block
        print("ola") < this is the statement in the finally one
        return r
Errors:
        do nothing < this is the pass instruction.
        var r = print ("ola")
        return r 

print(bool_return())
```

Ignore for a moment the `return` statement which might not be correct, the culprit of your question is how the interpreter runs the statements:

```
 return print("foo")
```

is broken down in two

```
var r = print("foo") < this is the statement in the try block
return r
```

and then the content of the finally is executed before the return

```
var r = print("foo") < this is the statement in the try block
print ("ola")
return r
```

This is because the semantics of the `try` block is the following

- run whatever is included in the `try` block. If it runs without errors, store the return value if present, then run the content of the `finally` block. If no errors occur here and we have a return value, just return that stored return value
- if the `try` block has an error, then run what is in the `except` block (if present). If no errors here good, store the return value if present, the run the `finalize` block, If no errors here, just return the stored return value
- if the `except` block as an error, the execution is stopped and the `finally` block is run. Then the exception is propagated to the outer block.
- and now things can get messy, as you can (and will) nest multiple `try` blocks. The above mentioned steps repeat recursively until either the exception is handled or the interpreter `try` block is reached. In the latter case, the application is stopped and the exception is printed to the console with the usual `traceback` syntax.

This is just to give you an insight about how it works. Certain details might miss or might be not 100% correct. If you want to have more information, you can play with exceptions at [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) and learn more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).